# External drive keeps getting mounted under /media/ even though I have it in fstab under /mnt

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab, btrfs

I have 3 physical external USB drives.  All are btrfs.  Two are combined into a single volume, the other is not.  The two volumes are both in `/etc/fstab` to be mounted at `/mnt` and that works fine, but the combined one also [keeps getting automatically mounted in `/media`, like a removable USB flash drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Automounting), and I don't know how to turn this off.

`/etc/fstab`:

```
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=619c1750-218e-4432-bb13-732a9c9192b5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3449-605A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

UUID=31abab38-ca1f-4541-9141-9506098d832a /mnt/butter auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=3f8633ef-aad6-4444-87b6-831a11c3067e /mnt/Int_Butter auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=2679ca57-e8e3-4b23-8574-69d751d62dbc /mnt/Risky auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

All 3 are mounting to `/mnt/` as they should, but `butter` is also being mounted to `/media/` as if it were a USB thumb drive.

Comment: That would suggest the mount in `/etc/fstab` is not working properly.

Comment: @vanadium It is working, though...

Comment: @nobody What am I supposed to learn from lsblk?  It's mounted at /mnt/, which I already know.  There's nothing in `/var/log/syslog` except it being mounted to /mnt/

Comment: Do you have a /swapfile or swap partition on the drive? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @heynnema No, it's just a btrfs volume taking up the whole drive. I don't think fstab is related to `/media/` mounts?

Comment: @endolith see if my answer works :)

Comment: @mook765 But it's not failing.  It's mounting to two places at once, and I only want fstab to be followed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu desktop then it comes with an application which automount usb by itself, anyway if you want more info about it please check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

As the link states you can change behavior in dconf-editor.